# Convergence of the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Does this product converge?
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$$

any hint?

Comment: It is depends on your definition of convergence of the product. It is not uncommon to say that this product _diverges_ to zero. This is because the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right)$ is divergent.

Comment: I was confused about this fact: The product of positive real numbers$ a_n<1 $, 
$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
converges if and only if the sum
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n$ 
converges. So how this doesn't contradicts MJD answer below? (btw, by converge I mean finite)

Answer (score 2):

Your hint is: It's the product of a lot of numbers each of which is between 0 and 1.

Comment: So it is like $a_{n}<1$, then $a_{1}<1$, $a_{1}a_{2}<a_{2}<1$, $a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}<a_{3}<1$, and so on!

Comment: Can we find the exact value of the product?

Comment: try multiplying the first 5 terms by hand or with a calculator

Comment: very small number!

Comment: @MJD: But I think this method doesn't work if we have $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$, right?

Comment: @mathst., I would have pointed out that all the numbers being multiplied are positive and no larger than $1/2.$